# How can I pass an Image from one activity to another in Xamarin Android?

Tags: c#, android, mobile, xamarin, apk

I have an ImageView in an activity with an image in Xamarin Android project. I need to pass that image to another activity by clicking a button.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(SecondActivity));
intent.PutExtra("Key", "Value");
```

I know the above method to pass string etc. But how can I pass an image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Passing Data Between Activities**

https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/fundamentals/activity/pass_data_between_activity/

You'll want something like this as an example:

```
Intent intent = new Intent (MediaStore.ActionImageCapture);
App._file = new File (App._dir, String.Format("myPhoto_{0}.jpg", Guid.NewGuid()));
intent.PutExtra (MediaStore.ExtraOutput, Uri.FromFile (App._file));
StartActivityForResult (intent, 0);
```

**Source:**

https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/other_ux/camera_intent/take_a_picture_and_save_using_camera_app/